# Passing a function from an abstract class

Tags: c++, polymorphism, abstract-class, derived-class

I'm trying to pass down the print function from an abstract class "shape" to the derived classes "circle" and "square". It should print out "Name: " followed by the name of the shape. For some reason, it isn't working right. Do I need to re-declare and re-define print for each derived class? Or did I not pass it down properly or is the name is not stored properly in the derived functions?

For clarification: I just want to make it print out the names properly as it loops through the array. Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks!

These should be the pertinent bits of code:

print() is declared in the shape header file.

```
In shape.cpp

void shape::setName( const string &shapeName )
{
    name = shapeName;
}

//return name
string shape::getName() const
{
    return name;
}


void shape::print() const
{
    cout<<"Name: "<<getName()<<endl;
}
```

constructor in square: //(identical to other derived classes)

```
square::square(const string &name, const int &sideLength)
    : shape ( name )
{
    setSideLength(sideLength);
}
```

In the main:

```
//create derived class objects with side lengths:
    square square1(
        "square", 3);

//an object array named shapesArray is created with an instance of square and circle

for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    {
        shapesArray[x]->print();
        cout<<"The distance around this shape is: "<<shapesArray[x]->getDistanceAround()<<endl;
```

Comment: _Pass_ the print function? Do you mean overload it? Did you make it virtual (it looks like you're calling from a pointer)?

Comment: I think I'm trying to pass it. Someone told me to use a pointer to it rather than doing print(). I thought that the print function would be contained by the derived class as well as the original function, but it won't print out their names.

Comment: Is `print()` defined in your `shape` class or in `square` class?

Comment: Can you please post the implementations of `print`?

Comment: @R Sahu The only places I use or reference it are in the code I have copied here. Should I have a specific implementation for each derived class in their cpp files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is as below.note that you need to set "name" correctly for the derived classes either by calling setname method exclusively or in their constructors itself.

```
  class Shape
  {
   public:
   string name; 
   void setName( const string &shapeName )
   {
     name = shapeName;
    }
   string getName() const
  {
   return name;
   }
   void print() const
  {
   cout<<"Name: "<<getName()<<endl;
   }
  };

  class Circle:public Shape
  {
   public:
    Circle()
    {
      name = "Circle";
    } 
   };

   class Square:public Shape
   { 
    public:
    Square()
    {
      name = "Square";
    }
    };
  int main()
  {
   Shape* shapesArray[5];
   shapesArray[0]->setName("check");
   Circle lCircle;      
   shapesArray[1]=&lCircle;
   Square lSquare;
shapesArray[2]=&lSquare;  

   for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
   {
     shapesArray[x]->print();

  }
```

}

Comment: It was a weird thing in the constructor. Thanks for suggesting that I check it!

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use a pointer, it is best to use the C++ features of dynamic binding with a `virtual` function:

```
virtual string shape::getName() const //in shape
{
    return "shape";
}
virtual string square::getname() const //in square
{
    return "square";
}

shape *s();
s = &shapeobj;
s.getName(); //shape
s = &squareobj;
s.getName(); //square
```

Comment: I can't use virtual functions in this program, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

From your title, I assume you have an abstract base class for shape in a header shape.h, which you haven't shown us, and which **declares** print().

That counts as a **declaration** in each derived class. Now you need to **define** print() in each derived class, to provide an implementation. It looks something like:

```
void square::print() {
  // implementation
}
void triangle::print() {
  // implementation
}
```

Wherever you provide a **definition** in the cpp file, you also need to provide a **declaration** in the header file. The header is the declaration of your class, the cpp is just the implementation.

Comment: I have the print function defined in the definition/cpp file for the abstract base class.(forgot to include it earlier, sorry!) Does it need to be defined separately for each base class if it is intended to do the same function in each of the base classes?

Comment: Your questions are very confusing. There is only base class. See edit.

Comment: I could put all of my code on here, but that would be quite a bit. I have print declared in my base class header file. I have it defined in my base class cpp file. I do not mention it in my derived classes. I'm assuming from your answer that the function is not accessible from the derived classes unless I declAre and define it in each of the derived classes? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No, I didn't but your question seems to be still changing and I no longer have any idea how to answer. Do not post your entire code: you need to create a Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example [http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve]. Then ask the question you really want.